# Non-trivial selections using jQuery based on content of previous element

Tags: jquery

Consider the following markup:

```
<x>
   <y>code1</y>
   <z>stuff</z>
   <y>code2</y>
   <z>foobar</z>
</x>
```

Using jQuery, how do I select the `<z>foobar</z>` node in the given markup using the following rule: find the `z`-node that follows after a `y`-node which has a body containing `"code2"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('y:contains("code2") + z')
```